# ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization build fail with this error in Nextjs13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit

ReferenceError: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization
Build fail with this error when i trace it, the reason is when i try to call api with redux-toolkit

## when i remove the dispatch or commit the redux code from login the build sucussfuly

is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue in nextjs 13

````
Login.js


import { Box, Button, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import {
  button,
  mainContainer,
  searchField,
  upperMainContainer,
} from "./loginStyles";
import { loginAction } from "@/redux/slice/loginSlice";
import { Formik } from "formik";
// import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "@/redux/store";
function Login() {
  const dispatch =useDispatch()
  // const router = useRouter();
 const userData =useSelector((state)=>state.loginReducer)
  return (
    <Box sx={upperMainContainer}>
      <Box sx={mainContainer}>
        <Typography variant="main_heading">Login</Typography>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ userName: "", password: "" }}
          validate={(values) => {
            const errors = {};
            if (!values.userName) {
              errors.userName = "Required";
            }
            if (!values.password) {
              errors.password = "Required";
            }
            return errors;
          }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              // alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              dispatch(loginAction(values))
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 400);
          }}
        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            isSubmitting,
            /* and other goodies */
          }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={mainContainer}>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                variant="outlined"
                type="text"
                name="userName"
                sx={searchField}
                placeholder="User Name"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                value={values.userName}
              />
              {errors.userName && touched.userName && errors.userName}
              <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                variant="outlined"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                sx={searchField}
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                value={values.password}
              />
              {errors.password && touched.password && errors.password}
              <Button variant="contained" type="submit" sx={button} disabled={isSubmitting}>
                Login
              </Button>
            </form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Login;

```
```

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { dispatch } from "../store";
const initialState = {
  userData: {},
};

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "login",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getLogin: (state, action) => {
        state.userData = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
export default loginSlice.reducer;
export function loginAction(values, router) {
  return async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:7700/api/v1/login`,values);
        dispatch(loginSlice.actions.getLogin(response.data.data));
      if(response){
        {router.push(`/home/${response?.data?.data?.user?.userName}`)}
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}```
````